# French Character Encoding in Webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, encoding

I am having trouble with encoding / decoding French character in my webapp.
The technology stack looks like:

- a utility jar that has encode / decode for French characters compiled with target Java 1.5
- a war that will be compiled with maven with target Java 1.5
- Tomcat 5.5.17 / JVM 1.5.0_06-b05

I have a utility class to encode/decode as follow:

```
public static String encodeFrenchCharacters(String src)
{
    String output = src;
    logger.info("[encodeFrenchCharacters] start: " + output);

    output = output.replaceAll("è","&egrave;");

    logger.info("[encodeFrenchCharacters] end: " + output);
    return output;
}

public static String decodeFrenchCharacters(String src)
{
    String output = src;
    logger.info("[decodeFrenchCharacters] start: " + output);

    output = output.replaceAll("&egrave;","è");

    logger.info("[decodeFrenchCharacters] end: " + output);
    return output;
}
```

And I wrote a simple Java program to test the functionality:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        String s1 = "è è è test 2";
        System.out.println("s1: " + s1);

        String s2 = encodeFrenchCharacters(s1);
        System.out.println("s2: " + s2);

        String s3 = decodeFrenchCharacters(s1);
        System.out.println("s3: " + s3);
}
```

As expected, everything works fine:

```
s1: è è è test 2

[encodeFrenchCharacters] start: è è è test 2
[encodeFrenchCharacters] end: &egrave; &egrave; &egrave; test 2
s2: &egrave; &egrave; &egrave; test 2

[decodeFrenchCharacters] start: &egrave; &egrave; &egrave; test 2
[decodeFrenchCharacters] end: è è è test 2
s3: è è è test 2
```

So the above looks good.
This utility class is in a jar compiled through maven:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

And separately, I have a webapp (war) that include the helper jar.
In the Servlet inside the war, it receives a POST with the body containing the String

```
&egrave; &egrave; &egrave; test 2
```

Then after reading the POST body, I pass it through the decode function, and I got this as a result:

```
[decodeFrenchCharacters] start: &egrave; &egrave; &egrave; test 2
[decodeFrenchCharacters] end: Ã¨ Ã¨ Ã¨ test 2
```

in Tomcat server.xml I already have:

```
<Connector port="8383" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
/>
```

in my Servlet doPost I have also tried adding

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

What's going on here?
Why does it work when I run it in simple Java program (ran locally on my machine), then when I deploy it as a war to tomcat, it can't handle the French characters?

Side note: My first try was actually not using the utility class that manually replaces French character, I was using Java's URLEncode and URLDecode that gives me %C3%A8 which is fine, but same problem as above, when I try to decode I end up with Ã¨ rather than è

Thanks for your help

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back. It turned out that the problem was the encoding used in the browser (ie from HTML file). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096618/special-and-accented-characters

Comment: there's no browser involved. The steps already got inside the tomcat/war where it find itself as &egrave; and when it tries to decode it, it ends up with the unrecognized character Ã¨, also I've done the steps mentioned in that issue to set server.xml Connector encoding as well as the request encoding

Comment: Why do you encode those characters in the first place? Generate HTML encoded in UTF-8, and nothing needs to be encoded (except of course HTML special characters: `<`, `&`, `>`,`'`, `"`).

Comment: If I don't encode the è from the point where it calls the Servlet, when it gets to the Servlet it automatically becomes Ã¨. So really, seems like the issue is somehow the war/Servlet cant handle French characters

Comment: Actually, when I dont do encoding, my servlet sees the french character as ï¿½

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Is it just from your logging to System.out? Bear in mind that if this is to the console or even a file (by default) then it probably won't support UTF-8. How about opening a file using UTF-8 and writing to that to check?

Comment: You might want to use "\u00E8" instead of "é" in your source code... otherwise, you can get strange behavior under certain circumstances.

Comment: What is your default file encoding (system property "file.encoding")? If it's not UTF-8 then you might be seeing the garbling occurring at the log-file level and not anywhere that matters.