# Unicode characters (Arabic letters) show up as question marks in IDE console

Tags: jsf, utf-8, character-encoding, console

I am using JSF 2.0 and I have text field as

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.myValue}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myBean.printMe()}" />
</h:form>
```

```
public void printMe() {
    System.out.println("first line==" + myValue + "==");
    System.out.println("second line==يشسيبشسيبشسيبشيس==");
}
```

When I run this project and enter `يشسيبشسيبشسيبشيس` in textbox, in IDE console I see as below.

```
INFO: first line==????????????????==
INFO: second line==????????????????==
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Its almost certainly character encoding, but can you give more detail please? Where the does the data come from? Where do you see the ??? (in the browser?)

Comment: Could you please check this link 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060752/how-to-display-text-in-serbian-russian-and-arabicjsf-2-0][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060752/how-to-display-text-in-serbian-russian-and-arabicjsf-2-0

Comment: JSF2/Facelets uses UTF-8 by default already, so this problem is pretty strange. Where exactly is `fullName` definied? A hardcoded bean property?

Comment: System.out.println not always deal properly with utf-8, try:
PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
stream.print("my name while entering is " + new String(fullName, "UTF-8"));

Comment: @user902383: Terrible. That's not a solution. That's a hack/workaround. See my answer for the real solution.

Comment: I had a similar problem, it turned out to be how the browser interpreted meta info in the HTML doc. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096618/special-and-accented-characters

Comment: @klonq: This is unrelated. `System.out.println()` doesn't print to HTML. Further, see also OP's other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451061/why-arabic-letters-are-not-inserting-in-database

Comment: @BalusC : I have updated question. Could you please take a look? I don't understand why `System.out.println("second line==يشسيبشسيبشسيبشيس==");` is giving me output as `second line==????????????????==`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by using the wrong console encoding.

The line

```
System.out.println("My Data is " + fullName);
```

prints to the standard output (stdout). You need to configure it to use UTF-8 as well. Assuming that you're using Eclipse, then you need to change the stdout encoding to UTF-8 by *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding*.

[image]

If you're using Netbeans, which I can't answer from top of head, head to this answer: [hebrew appears as question marks in netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662146/hebrew-appears-as-question-marks-in-netbeans) which contains a link to this [Netbeans Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqI18nProjectEncoding) which mentions the following:

> To change the language encoding for a project:
>
> 1. Right-click a project node in the Projects windows and choose Properties.
> 2. Under Sources, select an encoding value from the Encoding drop-down field.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, those lines in the filter are unnecessary

```
    res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    res.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

They defaults in case of JSF2/Facelets to proper values already. Remove those lines.

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant. Java is platform independent and you're using Eclipse, right?

Comment: Then configure it in Netbeans settings. I've never really used Netbeans, so I can't tell that from top of head. The OS platform (Mac/Windows/etc) is irrelevant for Java.

Comment: that means output that is storing in DB is proper. I will check another question answer for real problem.

Comment: I searched a bit and found a related question for Netbeans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662146/hebrew-appears-as-question-marks-in-netbeans

Comment: its UTF-8, but not sure why facing this problem? I will make site up with new changes and see what I am seeing.

Comment: Either Netbeans is doing mad or your concrete problem is caused by something else. Perhaps you're still printing data straight from DB? Anyway, have you tried Eclipse? Your question history contains hints that you've ever used it.

Comment: I am getting "??????" still when I make changes on live site. When I fire query `select summaryTitle from mySac002.patentInfo;` I see it as `ظا?? ت??????ة ??ت?????? صد???? ????ب??ئة  `. That means data is not entered correctly and it has gone as `?????????`

Comment: I also checked Netbeans for UTF-8 and its shows UTF-8 is used.

Comment: So you're still taking the DB's role into the question? This is then more related to your other question about the DB encoding. The current question (at least, the way as you formulated it), assumes just a pure `System.out.println()` of a submitted POST request parameter and NO single involvement of the DB here. In such case, other factors such as the stdout encoding play a role.

Comment: If I leave DB here, I still get `?????` while printing fullName value. I printed the data on server on live website and in catalina.out (live server and not localhost), I see output of `System.out.println("my name while entering is " + fullName);` as `my name while entering is ??????????? ????? ????? ????? ???` Some times I am getting ????? and when client tried to enter data, it get output as `Ù?Ø¸Ø§Ù? ØªÙ?Ù?Ù?Ø© Ù?ØªÙ?Ù?Ù? ØµØ¯Ù?Ù? Ù?Ù?Ø¨Ù?Ø¦Ø©`

Comment: So the server is not controlled by the IDE and thus the server output doesn't appear in IDE console? In that case, the IDE encoding plays NO role. You should be changing the encoding in Tomcat's/JRE's stdout (logging) configuration itself. In the main `logging.properties` file which is actually been used by Tomcat, you should be adding `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.encoding=UTF-8` line.

Comment: In IDE, I was testing locally. So I was talking about Netbeans. When I make site live with changes, I upload WAR file. As I am putting my WAR file on hosting website, I can see System.out.println() output in catalina.out file. When I open catalina.out file, I see there as ????????. I just tried to insert the text as `شسيبشسيبشسيب` and it gives me output as `?????????????????`

Comment: Yes. Did you understand my previous comment? As far as I understand you, the IDE console encoding is perfectly fine (i.e. Netbeans/Eclipse doesn't print question marks at all) and your current problem is that the production server still writes question marks to log file? Yes? Well, the answer in my previous comment still applies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19762/discussion-between-fahim-parkar-and-balusc)

Comment: Well, it's still definitely an encoding misconfiguration in Netbeans. Have you tried Eclipse?

Comment: nope, I have to download Eclipse for that. if its Netbeans problem, then WHY I get `????` when I take it to live server? As JSF is printing `?????` in database also, `????` is getting stored

Comment: Sigh. JSF doesn't do that. It's the server or Netbeans who's doing that. The DB problem is a completely different matter which is already answered in your other question about MySQL encoding. Just fix the JDBC connection parameters and ignore the sytem.out.println result and you'll see that it ends up fine in the DB.

Comment: I understand it can be Netbeans problem, however when I make site live, there is no Netbeans. There I upload WAR files. Why I also get `??????` at live site also?

Comment: Because, as already explained in a previous comment, the live server isn't been configured to use UTF-8 for stdout/logging. You're seeing a bunch of different but closely related environment-specific problems as single whole problem caused by JSF. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: Okay, I will do that... Will get back to you. But one question. On Terminal when I login through SSH using my id n oassword and fire query `select fullName from personalDetails` there also I see `????`. Yes Yes Yes, first I will try with what you said and get back to you.

Comment: If those question marks are stored as such in the DB (which is confirmed by looking **directly** in DB using some DB admin tool), then you should empty the DB table and re-insert the content using proper encoding (which is to be specified by JDBC connection parameters), as answered in your other question about DB encoding. There is no other way to fix the question marks in the DB. It's during that step too late already. And again, this initial question should have nothing to do with the DB. Redisplaying stored question marks from DB has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score -2):

If the data comes from a DB, please check the field datatype is nvarchar.

Comment: I didn't said data is coming from database. I am printing data of textfield before storing and I see that data itself is wrong. So I am worried why this is happening.

Comment: A wrong encoding in DB would only cause Mojibake, not question marks.

Comment: @BalusC : Any reason why this is happening? Also can you take a look at [this question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451061/why-arabic-letters-are-not-inserting-in-database)